# Glides offset: ɪ/ʊ or j/w?

Tags: ipa, phonetic-symbols

I've seen linguistics arguing in favour of using either ɪ/ʊ or j/w sets in glides offset. What are your arguments regarding the use of them?

Comment: Related: [Why is the “long i” sound in English written /aɪ/?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/26977) In the context of English phonemic transcriptions, I don't see that it particularly matters which one you use, unless someone else is demanding that your transcriptions conform to some specified format for some reason. If you are interested in how these symbols are used in other contexts, it would help if you could specify what languages and types of transcription you are asking about.

Comment: [Kenyon and Knott](https://archive.org/stream/pronouncingdicti00unse#page/n5/mode/2up) used /ɪ/ to mark the final syllable in _easy_, though most American linguists continue to transcribe (and pronounce) it as /i/. The issue doesn't arise for /ʊ/, because American phonemic practice doesn't transcribe the diphthongized tense vowels, instead using single vowel symbols and relegating the automatic glides to allomorphy, not represented phonemically. Plus, of course, American English /o/ isn't centralized to /əʊ/ like RP.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
I don't feel like using ɪ and ʊ in glides offset because I don't pronounce them like that. I don't pronounce "may" as [meɪ] or "south" as [saʊθ] if we consider the real sound of ɪ and ʊ. I can't even pronounce that. But there are people who are against the use of j and w because they'd be consonant sounds.
In the case of the word "easy" or words ending with "-ly", the RP transcription is [i], but it's pronounced as a diphthong [ɪj] for many people in England and even as [ɪ] in old-fashioned posh RP.

Comment: What is your basis for claiming that you don't pronounce the off-glides "like that" – i.e. what is your standard of comparison?

Comment: We have the same kind of dyphthongs in Portuguese and we don't pronounce the sound ɪ in these diphthongs, even though they are represented with this symbol by many linguists. If I try to pronounce these diphthongs with that sound, it sounds really odd.

Comment: I've just found some discussions about this subject and I've figured out they have no end. Each linguistic has their own viewpoint.

Comment: Well, if we use [eɪ] for FACE, how would we transcribe the old-fashioned RP more open offset of FACE?

Comment: Also, how to transcribe the HAPPY and even FLEECE diphthong with onset in [ɪ] of English English accents?